# MIPS QTSPIM 64bit

Tags: mips

So I'm using QTSPIM and I know MIPS can only handle 32-bits. This is also an assignment too, just to put it out there.

So the purpose is for me to be able to display factorial(14). At the moment, the program can only go up to factorial(12) I believe. How hard would it be to be able to support 64-bit. I know somewhat that I need to store the upper 32 bit and lower 32bit?

Could someone provide hints or sample code?

```
    # Iterative program to compute n!

            # The value n is entered by the user

            .globl  main
main:
            li      $v0, 5
            syscall                 # Get user input for n
            move    $s0, $v0        # s0: n

            move    $a0, $s0        # put n into first parameter
            jal     factorial
            move    $s1, $v0        # s1: n!

            move    $a0, $s1    
            li      $v0, 1
            syscall                 # display n!            

            li  $v0, 10
            syscall

#-----------------------------------
            # Factorial Function
            #
            # Parameters:  a0 - n
            # Return Values: V0 - n!
factorial:
            #---------------------- Stuff at beginning of function
            addi    $sp, $sp, -12   # space for 3 values
            sw      $ra, 0($sp)
            sw      $s0, 4($sp)
            sw      $s1, 8($sp)

            #---------------------- body of function
            move    $s0, $a0        # s0: n
            li      $s1, 1          # s1: n! (init to 1)
            li      $t1, 1          # t1: loop exit test value
floop:      ble     $s0, $t1, done  # when n decrements down to 1, exit
            mul     $s1, $s1, $s0   # s1 = s1 * n
            addi    $s0, $s0, -1    # n--
            j       floop

            #---------------------- Stuff at end of function
done:       move    $v0, $s1        # put n! into return register
            lw      $ra, 0($sp)
            lw      $s0, 4($sp)
            lw      $s1, 8($sp)
            addi    $sp, $sp, 12
            jr      $ra             # TTFN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the two operand form of the multiply instruction `MULT $s1,$s0`, it places the 64 bit product of `$s1` and `$s2` into the `HI` and `LO` special registers.

You can use this feature to calculate a 64 bit factorial with some extra work. Specifically, once the product exceeds 32 bits, you will need write code to do the equivalent of elementary school long multiplication.